# how to run ejabberd with Erlang on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to create a realtime private chat app running on ejabberd in Erlang. I am trying to install the same on Heroku. I am aware on how to run Erlang on Heroku but I don't know how to get ejabberd running on Heroku for my application. I am completely new in developing realtime chat app but I am thinking to make it scalable. Please anyone can tell me how to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using source code form github.

After compiling with

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make rel
```

there should be `rel/ejabberd/bin/ejabberdctl` executable, and adding

```
web: ./rel/ejabberd/bin/ejabberdctl start
```

to your `Procfile` should be enough to start the server.

Comment: On running ./autogen.sh command on Mac, I get this error: ./autogen.sh: line 2: aclocal: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 3: autoconf: command not found

Comment: I guess you need `autoconf` tools installed. It is not part of [official requirements](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd#0-requirements), or maybe they assumed they will be installed with make.

Comment: I am trying to install aclocal and autoconf using brew. Thanks for solution. I still have to try it.

Comment: I did found the ejabberdctl executable at the correct place in local but when i pushed my code to heroku, it was not able to start the ejabberd server

Comment: Why? Any errors? Any problems? Did you try to turn it of and on again? ;)

Comment: I get this error when i try to run on Heroku:

/app/rel/ejabberd/erts-6.2.1/bin/erlexec: 1: /app/rel/ejabberd/erts-6.2.1/bin/erlexec: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

.As I am not much aware of Erlang, I am trying to use python on Heroku. If I use foreman start on my local system, ejabber starts but on Heroku, it is not. I think the issue is Erlang not installed on Heroku. Also, I want to tell you that I am developing on Mac