# how to run ejabberd on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, ejabberd

I am trying to run ejabberd on Heroku but it says 
2014-11-30T09:55:19.790851+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/rel/ejabberd/erts-6.2.1/bin/erlexec: 1: /app/rel/ejabberd/erts-6.2.1/bin/erlexec: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

I will be interacting with the ejabberd node using python. Please help.

Comment: It seems ejabberd cannot really be started due to syntax errors in start scripts. You should review you scripts.

Comment: I have not pushed any custom script. ejabberd is installed properly on my Mac but it's not working on heroku.

Comment: But how do you install it on Heroku ?

Comment: Downloading github source of ejabberd from processone.Then i used 'make rel' command and then added the text "web: ./rel/ejabberd/bin/ejabberdctl start" in Procfile and pushed the contents of Folder 'rel/' to Heroku

Comment: If I use foreman start, then it starts the ejabberd server on my local but i think that Heroku is not having Erlang installed which is creating the problem.

Comment: Bulding on mac and deploying the result on Heroku ? Well, it cannot work as you are building Mac binaries and yes, Heroku is not really intended to run arbitrary application. You should deploy to EC2 directly and control your install.

Comment: Are you sure it is not possible on heroku? I do have wasted 2 weeks just to get it done. Still, I would like to confirm. Thanks

Comment: You are saying you are just copying your OSX directory over Heroku to a Linux server ? There is indeed no way you can expect this to work.

Comment: Please watch this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979875/how-to-run-ejabberd-with-erlang-on-heroku/26980321?noredirect=1#comment42932176_26980321 
I am following the commands suggested by mpm.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot build a Mac OSX version, upload it to a Linux server and expect it to work. The page you link explain how to build ejabberd, not specifically how to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: Does that mean, that i can get ejabberd working on Heroku if I build with those commands on Linux Server and then deploy it to Heroku?

Comment: No idea. I would not use Heroku to deploy ejabberd by a raw server. I would deploy on a Linux EC2 server for example and build there directly.

Comment: Thank You Michael. I don't want to use AWS directly right now.

Comment: Then, read: http://roberto-aloi.com/blog/2013/07/13/create-deploy-erlang-cowboy-application-heroku/ You need to use Erlang buildpack, but we did not test ejabberd with it, so this is not garanteed to work and you may have to troubleshoot that Erlang buildpack and ejabberd build on Heroku by yourself.

Comment: Thank You Michael. I am trying that only.